# Custom JavaScript - Not working in chrome

Tags: javascript

I have some custom javascript code which works great in firefox, however in chrome it seems to not respond at all, the page is located here:
http://wiki.tf2clan.co.uk/index.php/games/sizes

I would appreciate any input as to why chrome doesn't like this, and/or any alternative code snippets

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object <th>Game</th><th>Version</th><th>Size (GB)</th><th>Last Updated</th> has no method 'contains'`

Comment: ah that makes sence, I wonder why in firefox this works but does not in chrome, i'll change it to match then should work.

Comment: Changing to match indeed fixed my issue, I should know this by now :P

Comment: "Scene able"? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting errors on the filter:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

#### What I'm doing wrong?

```
for (i=0;i<50;i++)
{
    e = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
    z = e.innerHTML;
}
```

- You don't know if you will have always 50 elements.
- You are using incorrectly innerHTML
- You are calling `getElementsByTagName` in every iteration

#### Solution:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("tr").childNodes;
//Iterating through TR childs 
for(i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
    alert(nodes[i]);
}
```

**Alternative:**
If you are not a Javascript expert, I recommend to use jQuery to manage the DOM elements, it's cross browser and very documented. For example, you could do something like this with jQuery instead the whole `for` loop:

```
$('tr > td:not(:contains("+filter_text+")')).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

see chrome developer tools for Errors ctrl+shift+j